# Share intent message with hyperlink to my app in Google Play

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sharing, share-button

I have a `shareButton` in `optionsMenu` from where I would like to send a message via wasap, gmail... describing my app and **containing a hyperlink** to Google Play.

The problem is that the hyperlink doesn't appear, this is what I have done:

```
 mShareActionProvider =  (ShareActionProvider) MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(item);
    Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sharingIntent.setType("text/html");
    String shareBody = getString(R.string.sharing_intent_text)+"https://www.google.com/";
    sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, getString(R.string.sharing_intent_subject));
    sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
    mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(sharingIntent);
```

And here are the strings that I am using

```
<string name="sharing_intent_text">Game descrition <a href=https://https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=packageName>App Name</a> more description</string>
<string name="sharing_intent_subject">Subject</string>
```

Even if I use `sharingIntent.setType("text/html")` the name of the game isn't clickable.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem, I need to add this `Html.fromHtml(shareBody)` when I put the extra text in order to pass the string to Html format

```
sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(shareBody));
```